# Compressed SWF format not supported/cws2fws issue

Tags: ffmpeg, flash, compression

I am trying to convert .swf to a .flv file using ffmpeg. When I got that error, I searched around and found that I should use cws2fws to somehow decompress the .swf file so that it can be converted by ffmpeg. However, apparently I need to compile the cws2fws.c myself, but it requires so many other libs and files and none of them are located on any 1 site. Is there a precompiled version of cws2fws available somewhere for download, or can I solved my initial error some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found Moyeas command line SWF-to-Video and that does the job of converting `.swf` to `.flv` for me nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Precomiled for what platform, OS, etc? Better try go compile it yourself like this:

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git
cd ffmpeg/tools/
gcc -lz cws2fws.c
```

The output will be named `a.out`.

Reference: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/error-compiling-ffmpeg-tool-cws2fws-606577/

Comment: $ gcc -lz cws2fws.c 
cws2fws.c:9:20: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.